# Java deserialization in C++

Tags: java, c++, deserialization

I'm working on a `C++` application that has to process a variety of message types. One of the types is `serialized Java objects` (for which no source is available).
I'm wondering if anyone is aware of a C++ library along the lines of [`jdeserialize`](http://code.google.com/p/jdeserialize/)?
For those who aren't familiar with it, jdeserialize basically parses serialized objects and builds a graph.
It does a good job and I've been experimenting with it - using JNI to manage the interactions with the main program. 

This works correctly, but is cumbersome. I'm concerned that it will be a maintenance headache.

Comment: I doubt there is an elegant way to do this.  I suggest using a portable format like JSon instead.

Comment: Yes, you can just extract the data from serialized Java objects. I browse the jdeserialize and can not find something Java special codes. So I think you can write a C++ version of jdeserialize.

Comment: Agreed - I'm interested in finding out if someone else has already done this.

Comment: I think the best approach here is CORBA

Comment: @user2511414 Please elaborate.

Comment: read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/idl/tutorial/GSIDL.html and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24863/A-Simple-C-Client-Server-in-CORBA

Comment: @user2511414 Thanks, I know what CORBA is. I'm asking how it's relevant to my question.

Comment: You need to explain what you expect to do with this data, and how generalized it needs to be.  Simply interpreting a few objects is far different from creating an arbitrarily large and complex "mirror" data structure.

Comment: @HotLicks Fair enough.  My application displays the contents of the messages it processes (including the deserialized Java type of message).  It dumps a bunch of information, but as a simplifying assumption you could think of it as name-value pairs.  The name here will be the "path" to the value in the original data. Let's say that "a", (an instance of class A) has been serialized.  "a" has a data member "b" (of type B). "b" has a data member, "c", which is a double with the value 3.14.  The resulting name-value pair will be a.b.c = 3.14. These messages can have 100s of fields.

Comment: Of course, for that use JSON would be a much more reasonable choice, if you're not somehow constrained.

Comment: @HotLicks As a matter of fact, I've rigged up a mode where the deserialized data gets written out as YAML; it was quite straightforward. I expect writing JSON would be a similar undertaking.  I'm a little reluctant to build my tree in Java, convert it to a text representation, ship it to C++, and then have C++ build its own tree. It's certainly worth thinking about, though.

Comment: There's no real difference between converting a Java map or array to JSON than there is serializing it.  For maps and arrays (and numbers and strings) it's just a different serialization format (and one that's got good support on both ends, vs having to write your own).

Comment: @HotLicks The serialization of the objects is done by another organization entirely - that may be the constraint you alluded to earlier.

Comment: Yeah, that would be a "constraint".  Though producing JSON or some other standard form of output should be a reasonable request of the other group.

Comment: @HotLicks Unfortunately, that's a non-starter.

Comment: @user888379 Why can't you write a simple SerializedToJSON class in Java that deserializes the message and converts it into JSON? You can then embed the JVM in C++, load that class and let it handle the deserialization and conversion to JSON. Unless you are passing a lot of messages or have very tight memory requirements this approach should work decently.

Comment: @parry I've been assuming that this would be more-or-less what I described to HotLicks upthread - using the jdeserialize approach to parse the message, then do a pass over the resulting tree to produce a JSON representation.

Comment: @user888379 Actually it is simpler than that. You don't need jdserialize or any other external library. Just the JVM and standard boilerplate JNI code to load the JVM. Then you just write a standard Java class that takes in the serialized input, deserializes it, converts it to JSON (or whatever) and call it from C++ side using standard JNI mechanism. Or are you considering this approach to also be cumbersome? If that's the case I am afraid there aren't any easier alternatives that come to mind.

Comment: @parry Bear in mind that I don't have any information available about the serialized class.

Comment: Instead of attempting to port jdeserialize to C++, have you considered replacing it with Google's Protocol Buffers?

Comment: @JustinS I'm not seeing how that handles the parsing of the serialized data. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

Java ABI is not compatible with C++ one, so you can't do that. Objects are represented in memory in the different ways (and it is definitely not the only important difference but it should be enough).

Comment: Jdeserialize treats the serialized objects as a stream of bytes and does all the low-level parsing necessary to extract all the data, but it doesn't reconstitute the original objects - it builds a graph that can be interrogated to get various information about the objects.

Comment: @sasha.sochka I think that the OP does not want to deserialize Java objects into C/C++ objects but into a structure which can be inspected from C/C++ code directly.

Comment: @Patashu, OK, but how C++ objects have also some stuff like vptr, in C++ there is also multiple inheritance. You say C/C++ - there is no objects in C, but if OP means simple C structure and correspondingly simple Java classes without using any OOP stuff, of course, it would be easier, but should be stated explicitly

Comment: Patashu is right - I'm not trying to build C++ objects (or Java objects, for that matter) - I'm parsing serialized Java objects into, basically, a tree, with number and character data as the leaf nodes.  I use JNI calls from C++ to do a depth-first traversal of the tree, returning the primitive types.  What I don't like about this is having to fire up a JVM to do this, and having to feed arbitrarily structure data through JNI.  This is why I'm interested in finding out if there's a C++ equivalent to jdeserialize.

Comment: Is it Java `ABI` or `API`? just need to conform.

Comment: @jubinPatel I don't understand your question.

Comment: @user888379 this not for your question, this is for answer. @sasha.sochka start answer with `java ABI` here Its `ABI` or `API`? i am not aware about `ABI` that's why asking for same

Comment: ABI is a binary interface, not application. Objects are represented differently in memory (and this is binary interface)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to write the code first in Java, and then convert that code to C++. For a faster start, borrowing knowledge from java first, and step wise implementation, and emulation of some features (no need to deserialize an ArrayList). Maybe the source code of Jdeserialize, mentioned by @user888379, will do. Either way you probably want to deserialize the objects in Java too, for structural comparison with the C++ code.

Comment: I've got a pretty complete Java implementation working; I'm concerned about the maintainability and extensibility (particularly the JNI aspect).  Hence my interest in finding out if this is a solved problem (alternatively, I'm lazy and hoping that someone else has done the port).

Comment: @user888379 for the maintainability aspect, you may find convenient to use SWIG (http://www.swig.org/) to generate the skeleton of your C++ JNI library from a Java interface. It integrates pretty well in any build system.

Answer (score 0):

I would deserialize it in a JNI strapped JVM, and then use the Java methods to translate the data into the format that your C++ program will need.  There are just enough differences between Java and C++ that even if you could do it directly in C++, you would have to simulate a good chunk of the Java environment to make much sense of the data.

Serialized Java objects are rarely single objects, they often become "webs" of related objects, like an Object that contains a Map, with a number of Strings as keys that refer to who-knows-what as values.  And that's just one embedded attribute.

Comment: That's basically what I'm doing now - using jdeserialize and JNI.